# Augmented Reality app on Android using Unity3d with NyARtoolkit plugin, help needed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, unityscript

I am trying to implement an Augmented Reality app for the android platform, using Unity3d (free) with the help of NyARToolkit library plugin.

The following mock - up image shows the **GUI and basic functions of the app**:

[image]

Further more, I want my app to utilize the following functions:

Function 1:

The marker for model is recognized, and so is the marker for the info - avatar. If those two can be combined in one functional model recognized by one marker it would be awesome, **but don't know how it can be done.**

Function 2 (see image b):

[image]

-The model on touch event gives user position in relativity to the marker (not by GPS)
-On touch event of info (i) symbol, it changes view to an avatar giving some information on the spot and the about sections of the model in view. On back tap. it can be closed and return to preview, as info symbol (i).

Function 3:

The model on touch events can be:

- Translated
- Rotated on x (or y axes)
- Zoomed in-out (with a pinch maybe?)

Function 4 (see image c):

[image]

The model on touch events of distinctive sections can be interactive to the user by:
-Pop up txt
-Pop up image
-An animated path from section A to section B

This is the skeleton of the app I am trying to code. Till now I have tried touch events on the model (a cube, actually), without much luck.

My main questions are these:

- Should the GUI menu be overlayed on android device camera preview using code (Unity scripts) or be implemented on markers recognition only, **as virtual buttons**, that can be touched by user finger placed on marker?
- What steps to follow to make this GUI work, in both cases (overlay or on marker)?

So, I am in need of some advice, or a tutorial, or even better a sample code to move on this AR development.

Thank you all for you answers.